# How to to make properties visible when the Foreign Key comes up as ICollection<T> type in Entity Framework's .edmx's .tt classes [.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 Tables in the SQL Server SUST_HC_DTLS [Primary Key Column Name = SUST_ID] and the second table is SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS [Foreign Key = SUST_HANDLER (it references SUST_ID column of first table. This Table also has a Primary Key column = INC_NBR)].Now when i create the Entity Data Model. It create 2 partial classes for both the Table. As show Below --

**For Table = SUST_HC_DTLS (Primary Key Table)**

```
public partial class SUST_HC_DTLS
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public SUST_HC_DTLS()
    {
        this.SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS = new HashSet<SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS>();
    }

    public int SUST_ID { get; set; }
    public string HC_NAME { get; set; }
    public string HC_EMAIL { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> SHIFT_START { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> SHIFT_END { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> JOINED_ON { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UPDTD_AT { get; set; }
    public string UPDTD_BY { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS> SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS { get; set; }
   
}
```

**For Secondary Table = SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS (Foreign Key Table)**

```
public partial class SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS
{
    public string INC_NBR { get; set; }
    public string REASON_4_INC { get; set; }
    public string RAISED_BY { get; set; }
    public int SUST_HANDLER { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
    public string CURRENT_STTS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATED_ON { get; set; }
    public string DTLS_ENTRD_BY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UPDTD_ON { get; set; }
    public string DTLS_UPDTD_BY { get; set; }

    public virtual SUST_HC_DTLS SUST_HC_DTLS { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have separate Class Library for My Models for these respective Table and Below are the Classes in the Class Library --

**For Primary Table --**

```
public class HC_TBL
{
    [Required]
    public int SUST_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string HC_NAME { get; set; }
    
    [EmailAddress]
    public string HC_EMAIL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan? SHIFT_START { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan? SHIFT_END { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? JOINED_ON { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UPDTD_AT { get; set; }
    public string UPDTD_BY { get; set; }
    public INC_Trckr_TBL Trckr_TBL { get; set; }
}
```

**For Foreign Key Table**

```
public class INC_Trckr_TBL
{
    public string INC_NBR { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public string REASON_4_INC { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public string RAISED_BY { get; set; }
    public int SUST_HANDLER { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public string CURRENT_STTS { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CREATED_ON { get; set; }
    public string DTLS_ENTRD_BY { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UPDTD_ON { get; set; }
    public string DTLS_UPDTD_BY { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i do the Database Operations to get all records from the Database. Its not letting me call Foreign key properties /fields. It doesn't even provide them in the list.

However, when i do the LINQ Select from the options i get, i do get the property but then it gives me the error -- **Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to GDE.Model.INC_Trckr_TBL. An explicit conversion exists (Are you missing one?)**.

Now when i do the explicit conversion it says --
**System.NotSupportedException
HResult=0x80131515
Message=Values of type 'collection[Edm.String(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=20,Unicode=False,FixedLength=False)]' can not be converted to string.**

I Honestly don't know what to do anymore. Below is my DBOperations Repository Code --

```
public List<SustHCModel> GetAllDetails()
    {
        using (var context = new GDE_SUSTEntities())
        {
            var result= context.SUST_HC_DTLS.Select(x => new SustHCModel()
            {
                SUST_ID = x.SUST_ID,
                HC_NAME = x.HC_NAME,
                HC_EMAIL = x.HC_EMAIL,
                SHIFT_START = x.SHIFT_START,
                SHIFT_END = x.SHIFT_END,
                JOINED_ON = x.JOINED_ON,

                IncTrckrModel = new INCTrckrModel()
                {
                    INC_NBR = x.SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS.Select(y => y.INC_NBR).ToString(),
                    REASON_4_INC = x.SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS.Select(y => y.REASON_4_INC).ToString(),
                    RAISED_BY = x.SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS.Select(y => y.RAISED_BY).ToString(),
                    COMMENTS = x.SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS.Select(y => y.COMMENTS).ToString(),
                    CURRENT_STTS = x.SUST_INC_TRCKR_DTLS.Select(y => y.CURRENT_STTS).ToString()
                }

            }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I am new to this. So, i am pretty sure that i have made some mistake somewhere. So, please guide me and my apologies in advance for whatever silly mistake i have made.

Comment: Do you use database first or code first approach?

Comment: Database First Approach because the server is being maintained by different group. They have given me a service account with Read & Write access. However, Schema was prepared by the SQL DBA Team.